# Remote Form Renders as HTML instead of JS

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a simple form:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @bookcase], :id => "shelf_update_form", :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <input id="bookcase_image" class="file" type="file" name="bookcase[image]" size="13">
<% end %>
```

That automatically uploads when a file has been selected:

```
$("#shelf_update_form").change(function() {
  $("#shelf_update_form").submit();
});
```

I want the update action to render js view, but by default it renders html instead. I try forcing it to render js like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

But then I get this error:

```
NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable
```

Even then, my log reports:

```
Processing by BookcasesController#update as HTML
```

How can I get it to process as JS instead?

UPDATE:

The view:

```
triggerAjaxHistory("<%= @href %>", false);
```

I get the same results with a more generic view, too:

```
alert("I work now!")
```

Comment: Can you provide the view you've written for the action?

Comment: Updated with the code in my view.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the controller, do

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js if request.xhr?
   end
   ```
2. Is your view named as `.js.erb`?
3. Can you check using firebug in your browser what exactly you are getting as the response? Turn on net logging and look at the response.
4. Also do you have the following in your layout?

   ```
   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
   ```
5. Can you put in `logger.info whatever_message` commands to make sure you the controller action executes and you go into the correct view?
6. What happens if you specify the js format specifically in the controller as

   ```
    class UserController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :js, :only => :update, :layout => 'false`
   ```
7. What happens if you specify the format in `form_for` as `:format => :js`
8. Is your form nested within another form?

Comment: 1) Yep. 2) The only response Firebug gives is the "NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable" error. 3) Yep, and I even have AJAX working perfectly in many other locations on my site. 4) Definitely going to the right controller action. I can even get it to render "triggerAjaxHistory("<%= @href %>", false);" by ending my action with render 'update.js.erb'. Unfortunately, it's rendered as HTML and not run as JS.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I added 3 more suggestions to try to pin the problem down.

Comment: Suggestion 6 was a major step in the right direction. According to the console, it's now "Processing by BookcasesController#update as JS". Strangely, though, it continues to render the code as text rather than actually executing it. Even if I put it in <script> tags with a $(function(){...}) call, it doesn't run.

Comment: @timothythehuman, Try adding the request.xhr? test given in the updated point 1 in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it throws the "NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable" error again. Just to update you, I tried rewriting this as an "upload" method, but I continued to get the error. I also tried inserting an actual submit button and removing the autosubmit function, but had no luck down that route either.

Comment: @timothythehuman, can you try this in in different browsers like IE and Firefox. Though I think it may not do anything if its server side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18888/discussion-between-timothythehuman-and-highbandwidth)